# Append column in a dataframe with string values

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pandas, typeerror

I have a case where I am trying to append the calculated percent value in a understandable format into a column in my dataframe called df. When I say understandable format the output into the column should go like `'40% Matched'`, like in the case below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Col1':[['Phone', 'Watch', 'Pen', 'Pencil', 'Knife'],['apple','orange','mango','cherry','banana','kiwi','tomato','avocado']], 'Col2': [['Phone', 'Watch', 'Pen', 'Pencil', 'fork'],['orange','avocado','kiwi','mango','grape','lemon','tomato']]})

df['Matched Percent'] = 'No Match'

for index,(lst1,lst2) in enumerate(zip(df['Col1'],df['Col2'])):
   if(lst1 == lst2):
      print('100% Matched')
   else:
      c1 = Counter(lst1)
      c2 = Counter(lst2)
      matching = {k: c1[k]+c2[k] for k in c1.keys() if k in c2}
      text = '% Matched'
      if len(lst1) > len(lst2):
         out = round(len(matching)/len(lst1)*100)
         #df['Matched Percent'].append(out,'% Matched')
         print(out,'% Matched')
      else:
         out = round(len(matching)/len(lst2)*100)
         #df['Matched Percent'].append(out,'% Matched')
         print(out,'% Matched')

80 % Matched
62 % Matched

TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type "<class 'int'>"; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid
```

I keep getting TypeError. I tried a couple of ways but no luck. I am able to print the values in the way I want in my screen as shown above. But when I append it to my dataframe `df` it fails. Appreciate advice on how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic seems verbose. You can use a list comprehension:

```
zipper = zip(map(set, df['Col1']), map(set, df['Col2']))
df['Matched Percent'] = [len(c1 & c2) / max(len(c1), len(c2)) for c1, c2 in zipper]

print(df)

                                                Col1  \
0                 [Phone, Watch, Pen, Pencil, Knife]   
1  [apple, orange, mango, cherry, banana, kiwi, t...   

                                                Col2  Matched Percent  
0                  [Phone, Watch, Pen, Pencil, fork]            0.800  
1  [orange, avocado, kiwi, mango, grape, lemon, t...            0.625
```

Note there isn't much scope for optimizing such calculations with Pandas, which isn't designed to hold lists in series. If you need "pretty" output, you can use f-strings, supported in Python 3.6+:

```
print((df['Matched Percent']*100).map(lambda x: f'{x:.0f}% Matched'))

0    80% Matched
1    62% Matched
Name: Matched Percent, dtype: object
```

Comment: This works great. I see the output values look like decimals. It would be nice to print as percent. I tried this,  `df['Matched Percent'] = [((len(c1 & c2)/max(len(c1), len(c2)))*100) for c1, c2 in zipper]`. But can you make it better?

Comment: Just saw your comment. Pls ignore. will check it

Comment: I want to append the output as a percent to the `df['Matched Percent']` column. I tried your second code but it gives me the error. `ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'` My python version is `3.6.5`

Comment: Use assignment: `df['Matched Percent'] = df['Matched Percent']*100).map(lambda x: f'{x:.0f}% Matched')`. You are misusing `append`, in fact `append` should only very rarely be used.

Comment: Perfect. Your answer works like magic. Very fast run time. Thanks a lot._/\\_

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly,

> ```
> df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Col1':[['Phone', 'Watch', 'Pen', 'Pencil', 'Knife'],
>                             ['apple','orange','mango','cherry','banana','kiwi','tomato','avocado']], 
>                       'Col2': [['Phone', 'Watch', 'Pen', 'Pencil', 'fork'],
>                                ['orange','avocado','kiwi','mango','grape','lemon','tomato']]})
>
> df['Matched Percent'] = 'No Match'
>
> for index,(lst1,lst2) in enumerate(zip(df['Col1'],df['Col2'])):
>     if(lst1 == lst2):
>         print('100% Matched')
>         df['Matched Percent'][index] = '{}% Matched'.format(100)
>     else:
>         c1 = Counter(lst1)
>         c2 = Counter(lst2)
>         matching = {k: c1[k]+c2[k] for k in c1.keys() if k in c2}
>         text = '% Matched'
>         if len(lst1) > len(lst2):
>             out = round(len(matching)/len(lst1)*100)
>             #df['Matched Percent'].append(out,'% Matched')
>             print(out,'% Matched')
>             df['Matched Percent'][index] = '{}% Matched'.format(out)
>         else:
>             out = round(len(matching)/len(lst2)*100)
>             #df['Matched Percent'].append(out,'% Matched')
>             print(out,'% Matched')
>             df['Matched Percent'][index] = '{}% Matched'.format(out)
> ```

I expect that you have a df with the following condition:

```
import pandas as pd

result = 'blablabla'
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],
                  columns=['a','b','Match Percent'])
s = pd.Series(index=df.columns)
df = df.append(s, ignore_index=True)
df['Match Percent'][df.shape[0]-1] = result

print(df)

     a    b Match Percent
0  1.0  2.0             3
1  4.0  5.0             6
2  NaN  NaN     blablabla
```

I think this is what you want, right??

Correction:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2],[4,5]],
              columns=['a','b'])

df['Match Percent'] = (df['a']/df['b']*100).apply(lambda x: '{} Match'.format(x))


   a  b Match Percent
0  1  2    50.0 Match
1  4  5    80.0 Match
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Infact I am calculating the percentage of strings that match in two columns. So if you look at my question. I have already found out the ones that match. I am dividing the `len(matching)` which is the count of strings that match by `len(text)` which is the total count of actual strings. I am able to print the output as `40% matched`. But when I append this `40% Matched` by placing it in a variable called `result`. The append fails with a type error. So in your example. The column `Match Percent` should show `50% Matched` which is nothing but `a/b*100`. I hope its clear.

Comment: Correction to the above statement referring your example. If column `a` contains the number of matched values as 1.0 and `b` contains the total number of values. Then the matched percent will be `a/b*100`.

Comment: I dont understand how does your percent result in `0.02 match`, When the value is 1 in column `a` and 2 in column `b`. if there is one matching item out of 2 then it must be `50% match` right?

Comment: sorry, before that i type df['a']*df['b'] instead of df['a']/df['b'], i didn't edit the output ...

Comment: But could you go back to my example. You have done it using a test dataframe that you created. But in my example I am taking the length of two lists and then trying to build it. Do you think you can build something like that? My requirement is of that sort unfortunately.

Comment: I have edited the complete question. Please go through so you can understand. You will need to uncomment the hashes and then comment the print lines to see the error.